# [Mod page] Choosing 'flags' means that other option vanish

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderation

A moderators-only issue, and tiny but still there. From the 'mod' page, if I choose 'flags' then the other options all vanish. So I have to go back to get at them, whereas if I pick another option ('links', for example) I can still flick straight across to another choice.

Comment: I agree that this is a definite irritation - minor, but nonetheless irritating.

Comment: Since this involves the core engine (not specific to *this* site), it is better asked at http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I've posted it there: thanks.

Comment: Apparently this is 'by design' as the 'flags' tab is present in both the 'tools' and 'mod' pages.

Answer (score 4):

This [was reported by Joseph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61680/mod-page-choosing-flags-means-that-other-option-vanish) and it is not considered a bug but by 'by design'.

If it is still an issue I guess it would be best to make a new post about it since the post that Joseph's is marked as a duplicate of has been removed.